# Error while running jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, classpath

Steps followed

- mysql workbench installation
- Connector-J download and extract to Mysql folder in program files 
  Copied

  ```
  import java.sql.*;
  public class FirstExample {
  // JDBC driver name and database URL
  static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
  static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

   //  Database credentials
  static final String USER = "username";
  static final String PASS = "password";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Connection conn = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  try{
     //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     //STEP 3: Open a connection
     System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

     //STEP 4: Execute a query
     System.out.println("Creating statement...");
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     String sql;
     sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

     //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
     while(rs.next()){
        //Retrieve by column name
        int id  = rs.getInt("id");
        int age = rs.getInt("age");
        String first = rs.getString("first");
        String last = rs.getString("last");

        //Display values
        System.out.print("ID: " + id);
        System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
        System.out.print(", First: " + first);
        System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
     }
         //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
     rs.close();
     stmt.close();
     conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
     //Handle errors for JDBC
     se.printStackTrace();
  }catch(Exception e){
     //Handle errors for Class.forName
     e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
     //finally block used to close resources
          try{
        if(stmt!=null)
           stmt.close();
     }catch(SQLException se2){
     }// nothing we can do
     try{
        if(conn!=null)
           conn.close();
     }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
     }//end finally try
  }//end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
    }//end FirstExample
  ```

This code to new project in eclipse.
When  I run it this error occurred to me

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:17)
  Goodbye!
```

Then tried this cmd command

```
set classpath=C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-   
 connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar;
```

Still the same error 
what to do, please give some explanation along with your valuable solution 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

if you are not using maven then add this jar `com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar` to your `eclipse build path` 
`rightclick on project--> build path-->configure build path-->libraries-->add external jar`

Comment: @arunkumar glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

> You will have to copy the JDBC connector jar file into library folder of your project
>
> or in library folder of server
>
> Both works fine...
>
> Runtime variables are not getting it from these two locations

Comment: If you are still not getting what to do where to do, reply me with these details. 1. Which tool you are using for development.(Editor eg. eclipse or netbeans).  2. Which sever are you using (eg. tomcat or Glassfish).

Comment: Copied the single jar file `mysql server 5.7/lib` folder. same error is occurred. Do I have to set path or something

Comment: no no not in sql server's lib instead copy it on projects lib or Server(WebServer/Apache) lib

Comment: eclipse, Tomcat - but is't the problem is with connecting to mysql , thanks dude

Comment: For Tomcat lib, goto C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib and copy jar here,

Comment: Or For projects lib, goto your project folder on eclipse/Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib paste jar here will also work fine

Comment: I tried two of em, same error pointing to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: If Still not working, just send a scrnshot of your project with error msg, its too easy but tricky sometimes

Comment: oh, sorry I forget about yours.. I'll check it right now.

Comment: @Arunkumar , I saw that screen shots, one point I would like to share you about eclipse that, whenever using eclipse for J2EE always select mode "JAVA EE" yours is Selected on "JAVA" which might cause problem in future (even if working fine now.) And one more thing I forgot to add in above steps, that after pasting jar files to Server lib AND/OR project lib DO REFRESH YOUR PROJECT (by right clicking on project folder -> refresh). If you are not refreshing manually, you will need to modify the dependency.

Comment: Hope this helps you to improve better, and sorry for that I missed this info in previous solution, sorry again. Have a nice day!

Comment: I did check here once after I got the output, thanks for your help I follow your instructs in eclipse. I am thankful for your help. Have a nice day @manoj Shukla

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath contains a space therefore `java.exe` will not pick it up correctly.
 Use the caret character ^ to escape the space:

```
set classpath=C:\Program^ Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar;
```

(And double check that the path is correct!).

Comment: thankyou, I tired it, same error is again pointing to ClassNotFoundException. And the path is correct as well. @wero

Comment: Dear @wero, why is it pointing the exception at `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: @Arunkumar because this line fails. Java tries to load the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` but it can't find it in the classpath - since somehow the `mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar` is not part of the classpath

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot